# Prove difference of two series converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n=1/n^2\bigg(\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} k \log(\frac{1}{k})\bigg), b_n=1/n^2 \bigg(\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n (k+\frac{1}{2}) \log (\frac{1}{k+\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)$. We take $0\log 0=0$

I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(b_n-a_n)=0$.

I can see that as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ both $a_n,b_n$ equal the area under the curve $x \log(1/x)$ and thus their difference should tend to zero. How can I prove this rigorously ?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to add a multiplying term of $1/n^2$ before the sums. I edited the series now. I guess, it'll converge now.

Comment: @Hetebrij: Can you explain how ?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yeah, correct. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here, we have

$$\begin{align}
a_n-b_n&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left((k+1/2)\log (k+1/2)-k\log k\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac12 \log k+\left(k+\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac12 \log k+O\left(1\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}O\left(n\log n\right)\\\\
&\to 0 \,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty
\end{align}$$

and the series converges to $0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I forgot to add a multiplying factor of $1/n^2$ . Then the series converges right ?

Comment: Yes.  Then it converges to $0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{k \to \infty} (k+\frac 12)\log(\frac {1}{k+\frac 12})-k\log \frac 1k=\lim_{k \to \infty} \log \frac {k^k}{{k+\frac 12}^{k+\frac 12}}=\lim_{k \to \infty} \log \frac {1}{1+\frac {1}{2k}}^{k} \frac {1}{\sqrt {k+ \frac 12}}= -\infty$ (Because of the term $\frac {1}{\sqrt {k+\frac 12}}$).

Hence $b_n-a_n$ diverges as $n \to \infty$.